# Calling method in Java

Tags: java, mysql, methods

I want to connect with mysql db by using host, username, password from file aplikacja.properties. But I have problem bcs those method return null and I don't know why ?

getHost()

getUsername()

getPassword()

getDb()

```
package aplikacja.mysql;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Mysql {

    private String host;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String db;

    public void readConnectionParam() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Properties mysqlAplikacjaProperties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream mysqlPlik = new FileInputStream("aplikacja.properties");
        mysqlAplikacjaProperties.load(mysqlPlik);
        host = mysqlAplikacjaProperties.getProperty("jdbc.host");
        username = mysqlAplikacjaProperties.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        password = mysqlAplikacjaProperties.getProperty("jdbc.password");
        db = mysqlAplikacjaProperties.getProperty("jdbc.db");
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Mysql baza = new Mysql();
        System.out.println(baza.getUsername());

        Connection polaczenie = null;
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            polaczenie = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://" + baza.getHost() + "/" + baza.getDb(),
                    baza.getUsername(), baza.getPassword());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement statement = polaczenie.createStatement();
        String command = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname) VALUES (2, 'Tom', 'Suszek')";
        statement.executeUpdate(command);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `readConnectionParam()` Method since thesse fields are initialized here.

Try:

```
Mysql baza = new Mysql();
baza.readConnectionParam();
System.out.println(baza.getUsername());
```

Include the above code in a `try catch` since the method `readConnectionParam()` throws `Exception`s

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any code that calls the `readConnectionParam` method, which is the only thing that can initialize the variables that are returned in your methods that are returning `null`.  Call it.

Answer (score 0):

You should first initialize your vars calling the method

```
readConnectionParam
```

inside the main

Answer (score 0):

use -

```
baza.readConnectionParam();
```

after

```
Mysql baza = new Mysql();
```

statement.